# How to encode javascript function

Tags: javascript, encode

How can i encode my parameters in javascript?

This my function and my parameter called newvalue

```
<script>
function selectChanged(newvalue) 
{
location.href="tester?restid=" + newvalue;
}
</script>
```

This is how i tried with adeneos suggestion

```
   window.location.href = "tester?restid=" + encodeURIComponent(newvalue);
```

but this does not work.

This is what i am getting:

```
tester?restid=38619
```

This is want i want

```
 tester%3Frestid%3D38619%21
```

Comment: If the answers below aren't what you're looking for, please give us an example input and expected output.

Comment: I just updated it with an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function selectChanged(newvalue)  {
    window.location.href = encodeURIComponent("tester?restid=" + newvalue);
}
```

Comment: i am getting this is my url tester?restid=38619 ... i want the restid=38619 to be encode like this  tester%3Frestid%3D38619%21

Comment: @Zaz - just include the rest in the encoding, changed the answer !

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
location.href="tester?restid=" +encodeURIComponent( newvalue );
```